# Issue in reading CSV files using Flask in Google Compute Engine

Tags: python, pandas, google-compute-engine

I am reading a fairly large CSV file using pandas.

```
csvfile = pd.read_csv('static/somefile.csv', low_memory=False, chunksize=50)
```

The files are stored in a static folder on a Google Computer Engine.

I keep getting two errors:

```
1)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 182, in cb
File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 192, in handle_abort

2)
csvfile = pd.read_csv('static/somefile.csv', low_memory=False)
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
```

I have increased the memory and CPU as much as I can on the Engine so I know it's not that. 
In error (2) it is ignoring the 'chunksize' parameter. I'm not sure if this is an issue with flask?

Is there something you unique to flask you need to read a CSV file using pandas?

*note this is in a separate python file to the main flask app

Comment: How big is your CSV, how many lines/MB?
Did you try to load it in an ordinary python session - without Flask?

Comment: 230mb, it loads fine in a normal python session

Comment: Is the main flask app using a ton of memory on its own?  How much memory are you using without loading this file?